# VueJS check periodically global function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a VueJS project where I need to **check periodically** a function to see if a token has expired once the user login to the app successfully and if the token has expired have to show a modal message to user.

I have my Singin.vue file that contains the following code:

```
....
 methods: {
    ...mapActions(['authorize']),
    submit() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then(result => {
        if (result) {
          this.error = null;
          this.processing = true;
          this.authorize(this.credentials).then(() => {

            // ***********
            // HERE I have to check periodically if the token has expired
            // ***********

            this.$router.push({name: 'home'});
          }).catch(error => {
            console.warn('error message', error);
            this.error = error.response.data.message;
            this.processing = false;
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

When `this.authorize` happens I route to home, but before that happens I need to start calling a function periodically. Then If user Logoff then I have to clear the interval.

So first, I don't know where is the best place to have this TokenExpiration function code. Does it make sense to have it in a store file?

This is my `api.js` store file where I have my `authorize` function and my `logout` function, does it make sense to have the `tokenExpirationCheck` function here also?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it, but I would probably solve this using a plugin, because timers should not be in the store, and the behavior is global to the application, so I wouldn't put it into any single component.

The pugin would have a vuex.watch on the stoere's logged-in flag. When it goes from `false => true`, remove the timer (if active) and if it goes from `false => true`, add the timer. The timer function can then call the vuex dispatch to handle the functionality.

Comment: Do you know if there is already a plugin for doing this? Thanks a lot

Comment: Probably not, because this is custom functionality. But a vue plugin is not necessarily meant to be a collection of easily distributed functionality. It is also a way to add global functionality.